# Variable as Tar file name in SunOs 5.10

Tags: linux, shell, tar, sunos

I am trying to get the following result in the

1.files archived as tar with current date as a part of the tar name.
2.files removed once archived.

> /usr/sap/ST1/POC/backtest/*.txt has 2 txt files.

```
(find /usr/sap/ST1/POC/backtest/*.txt )| xargs -I % sh -c 'tar cvf arc_2017-02-28.tar % ; rm -f %'
```

This works fine as the file name is mentioned as arc_2017-02-28.tar.

But when I tried this:

```
arc_name="arc_"`date +%F`".tar"
(find /usr/sap/ST1/POC/backtest/*.txt )| xargs -I % sh -c 'tar cvf "$arc_name" % ; rm -f %'
```

The output is an error:

> tar: : No such file or directory

Please help me proceed with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would work normally :

```
(find /usr/sap/ST1/POC/backtest/*.txt) | xargs -I {} sh -c 'arc_name="arc_"`date +%F`".tar"; tar cvf "$arc_name" {} ; rm -f {}'
```

so the issue with your command was that `sh -c` seems that can't read your variable , if we can call that is variable scope so to speak ,

so moving the variable `arc_name="arc_"`date +%F`".tar"` into the `sh` makes sense .

but you will have to change the `%` in `xargs` because this will produce an issue with your `%` symbol in `date +%F` function

Comment: Thank you very much